# Edit header of Joomla website using Gantry framework

Tags: joomla2.5

My website URL is http://picofdel.org/

I want to make it Section 508 compliant by removing an empty link from the header. The empty link is shown at http://wave.webaim.org/report#/picofdel.org. It is in position header-a. But, no module with this position is listed under Modules Manager.

When I view page source the empty link code is shown in browser as:

```
<div class="rt-grid-8 rt-alpha">
<div class="rt-block">
<a href="/" id="rt-logo"></a>
</div></div>
```

The index.php has the following lines which is fetching headers

```
<div id="rt-header">
<div class="rt-container">
<?php echo $gantry->displayModules('header','standard','standard'); ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div></div>
```

So, how can I edit the code for header and in which file to remove the empty link?

Comment: It is the index.php file in your /templates/yourtemplate folder.

Comment: Yes..It is in the template folder.

Comment: That's the file that module position is listed. Remove that part.

Comment: The section is supposed to look like <json:include ... name="header-a">

Comment: there is no section like this in index.php file

Comment: Sorry, my answer was about native joomla template system, not experienced with Gantry directly. I wonder if you have a module.php file in the templates/gantry/html folder that probably has the related section overriding the template?

Comment: I am now able to look your page's source and I see that it is the main logo section of your page. It is not empty link, just leading to your home page since it is just href="/". Therefore I don't think that you'd really like to remove that section. Besides, I also looked at the Gantry settings and you can simply OFF the module to remove the section, not necessary to edit template files as I previously suggested.

Comment: No, I will only remove the empty link(with no text) not the entire header and turning it OFF in settings removes the entire header image. The empty link(link with href="/") has to be removed to make my client's website section 508 compliant.